# How to solve this error ”_OBJC_CLASS_$_MBProgressHUD", referenced from:?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, xcode8.2

I have an existing project with different project name & workspace name. There is no podfile in the application folder. It has Pods folder with Pods.xcodeproj file. All other files are missing. But we can open and run the project using workspace file. Third party libraries are added manually.  I have installed pod and created workspace with same name. I can open and run the application.

I have removed MBProgressHUD library and installed it using Cocoapods. After that I can’t run the application and got the following error message.

> "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MBProgressHUD", referenced from: objc-class-ref in
>   BlackboardGroupController.o  objc-class-ref in MenuController.o ld:
>   symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: check that  MBProgressHUD.m file is in the project

Comment: If you have removed MBProgressHUD accidentally and still wants to use it in BlackboardGroupController.h/.m then add them again.

Comment: or if you dont want to use this library anymore then remove #import "MBProgressHUD.h" from BlackboardGroupController as well

Comment: Check MBProgressHUD.m file is still in your build folder

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish  I have removed MBProgressHUD library and installed it using Cocoapods. After that I can’t run the application and got the following error message.

Comment: Make sure MBProgressHUD.m is checked under "Target Membership" for your project's target.

Comment: also,  try  **pod update** command in terminal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove all CocoaPods and Integrate again. Please do the following steps to remove Cocoapods.

1.Delete the standalone files (Podfile Podfile.lock and your Pods directory)

2.Delete the generated xcworkspace

3.Open your xcodeproj file, delete the references to Pods.xcconfig and libPods.a (in the Frameworks group)

4.Under your Build Phases delete the Copy Pods Resources, Embed Pods Frameworks and Check Pods Manifest.lock phases.

5.This may seem obvious but you'll need to integrate the 3rd party 
libraries some other way or remove references to them from your code.

pod deintegrate and pod clean are two designated commands to remove CocoaPod from your project/repo.

Here is the complete set of commands:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
$ pod deintegrate
$ pod clean
$ rm Podfile
```

Clear DerivedData :

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

Close Xcode and install cocoapods again